# How to remove role from list with Discord bot?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a username list like this:

```
['Username#0001', 'Username#0002'......]
```

And these users have "x" role.
I want to remove "x" role from these users with a bot command.
Any ideas?

Comment: Without any infomation about your data structure, it is totally impossible to give any hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you searched for this

We first get all the users in the guild. We iterate through the users and get all the roles the user has. When we have all the roles the user has we iterate through the roles. We then check if the name of the role is the same as the name of the role we want to remove. If it has the same name we remove it from the user.

```
role_to_remove = "NAME OF ROLE"
for user in ctx.guild.members:
    for role in user.roles:
        if role.name == role_to_remove:
            await user.remove_roles(role)
```

This code will check if any user in the server has the role you want to remove.

If you have a usernamelist in string format. You first want to convert them to member objects so you can do the thing described earlier. You can do this with using the following:

```
userlist = ['Username#0001', 'Username#0002'......]
new_userlist = []
for users in userlist:
    new_userlist.append(ctx.guild.get_member_named(users))
userlist = new_userlist
```

When you have converted the userlist replace `ctx.guild.members` with the new userlist.

Make sure to read the documentation:

[remove roles](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=remove_role#discord.Member.remove_roles)

[get member by name](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild%20get_member#discord.Guild.get_member_named)

[get member by user id](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild%20get_member#discord.Guild.get_member)

Comment: Looping through all the roles for each member is inefficient when you need the same `Role` object for each call to `Member.remove_roles`. It's also inefficient to loop through each username in the list to append to another list to use in a different for loop when the username list itself can just be used in that for loop. You also have a syntax error with a missing closing parenthesis when appending to the new list.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have the name of the role, you'd need to go through [`Guild.roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.roles) for the server in question to get the [`Role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role) object, e.g. by using the [`get`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get) utility function. You'd then need to go similarly through [`Guild.members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.members) and get the [`Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#member) object for each username and discriminator. Alternatively, [`Guild.get_member_named`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_member_named) does this for you.
Then, for each `Member` object, you can use [`Member.remove_roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.remove_roles) and pass the `Role` object to it to remove the role from the member.